# Does each Stack Exchange site keep its own reputation record for your profile?

Tags: support, reputation

I have a couple of Stack Exchange profiles, according to my various interests of course. I wonder, does each of these keep its own record of your reputation? For example, on Stack Overflow I have 11 rep, on Super User I have 11 rep, and on EEngineering I have 1. Is there any sort of total reputation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Exchange does have a combined reputation number and combined badge count, but it doesn't get you any privileges.  It is only shown on your Stack Exchange flair image, that you can post somewhere if you want.  Here is what my flair image looks like:

[image: profile for Ben Miller on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

The Stack Exchange reputation number only includes reputation from sites where you have more than 200 reputation, so you don't yet have any Stack Exchange reputation.  My Super User rep and badges are not included in this number currently, because I don't have 200 rep yet on this site.

Answer (score 11):

Reputation is accumulated on a per-site basis. However, once you earn 200 rep on *any* site, you automatically get a +100 bonus on all *other* sites. This is because once you earn 200 rep the system trusts you enough to use basic features like voting and commenting on all of the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

I find it increasingly difficult to actually find where the flair is for when I have forgotten so let me say how to actually get to the flair which provides the combined reputation and badges:

1. Go to the stack exchange site
2. Click on your username on the top banner.
3. Click on the flair link which is currently just above Top Questions and is the right most link.

Comment: You need to go first to "View network profile" to see the "flair" link.

Comment: From any individual stack exchange site.  Yes, so true.